# Как тестировать многопоточный код с Junit?

Tags: java, многопоточность, junit

У меня код, который нужно протестировать на потокобезопасность, я хочу сделать это при помощи `junit`, подскажите как это делается?

Вот код:

```
public class UserStorage implements Storage {
    private final Map<Integer, Account> accounts;
    private final Object monitor;

    UserStorage() {
        this.accounts = new HashMap<>();
        this.monitor = new Object();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAccount(final Account account) {
        synchronized (this.monitor) {
            final Account a = this.accounts.get(account.getId());
            if (a != null) {
                return false;
            }

            this.accounts.put(account.getId(), account);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Если тестировать этот метод, не в контексте многопоточности, то получается так:

```
@Test
public void whenAddNewAccountThenMethodNewAccountReturnTrue() {
    Account account = new User(new BigDecimal("1"), "name", 1);
    Storage storage = new UserStorage();

    boolean result = storage.addAccount(account);
    assertTrue(result);
}

@Test
public void whenAddNewAccountButAccountIdIsExistThenMethodAddAccountReturnTrue() {
    Account account = new User(new BigDecimal("1"), "name", 1);
    Storage storage = new UserStorage();
    storage.addAccount(account);

    boolean result = storage.addAccount(account);
    assertFalse(result);
}
```

И так далее...

Но, у меня задание в том, что-бы код был потокобезопасный, соответственно, я должен как-то, и протестировать его на это. Помогите пожалуйста, подскажите направление.

Comment: определитесь, что вы хотите тестировать. тестирование многопоточных  приложений не тривиальная задача. и юнит тестами ее нельзя сделать. почему вы используете блок `synchronized`?

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman мне дали задание сделать код потокобезопасным,  потому что я прохожу модуль по многопоточности.

Comment: вопрос почему используете блок, а не пометите метод?

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman я видел урок на котором говорилось что этот способ предпочтительней, и что если параметром в блок написать просто this то это будет тоже самое что в сигнатуре метода пометить. Это не правильно?

Comment: не правильно что? ваше утверждение? ваш код? урок которого я не видел?

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman утверждение и код)))

Comment: судя по всему вы не поняли урока. ведь у вас не **this**, а отдельный объект зачем-то добавлен. проверить синхронизирован ли метод можно легко, а вот блок не очень.

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman ну там был пример и с this и с отдельным объектом а разницы я не уловил. Мне сейчас кажется что блокируется только тот объект который в параметре блока, но зачем тогда отдельно объект монитор создавать не пойму?

Comment: почитайте про Культ Карго.

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman спасибо за вашу остроумную иронию, но думаю вы выбрали не то место.

Comment: если вы не знаете разницы, то значит надо ее узнать, а не копировать бездумно. если бы у вас был метод помечен, то вы бы легко проверили наличие метки. а так у вас нет простой возможности.

Comment: тестирование многопоточного кода в корне не имеет чего-то отличного от классического тестирования: вы моделируете ситуацию, в которой могут проявляться неожиданные эффекты, после чего проверяете, что все ок. здесь просто добавляется необходимость создания высокой конкуренции за ресурсы и принятие того факта, что прохождение теста не гарантирует стопроцентную корректность алгоритма.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поскольку вызывать ассерты не в потоке junit нельзя, то вы можете запустить тестовые треды через Executors а потом, например, создав барьер дождаться выполнения их всех и проверить уже что получилось.

P.S> Если у вас запись будет редкая, а чтение часто, то не используйте `synchronized`. Лучше всего `StampedLock` или если не Java 8, то `ReadWriteLock`.

Пример:

```
CompletableFuture future1 = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> { 
    // Выполняем что-то с тестируемым объектом в одном потоке 
}); 
CompletableFuture future2 = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> { 
    //Выполняем что-то с тестируемым объектом в одном потоке 
}); 
СompletableFuture.allOf(future1, future2).thenAccept(v -> { 
    //Делаем проверки 
}).get()
```

Comment: А не могли-бы немоного кода (хотябы один тестик с комментариями?)

Comment: CompletableFuture future1 = CompletableFuture.runAsync(()->{
                //Выполняем что-то с тестируемым объектом в одном потоке
            });
CompletableFuture future2 = CompletableFuture.runAsync(()->{
                //Выполняем что-то с тестируемым объектом в одном потоке
            });
СompletableFuture.allOf(future1, future2).thenAccept(v->{
    //Делаем проверки
}).get()

Comment: В чем профит в данной ситуации от StampedLock ?

Comment: Данная ситуация абстракция. StampedLock, хорош тем, что как и ReadWriteLock позволяет брать блокировки отдельно на чтение и отдельно на запись, но помимо этого обладает уникальным свойством - можно произвести "оптимистичное" чтение, и если оно будет успешным, то блокировку на чтение можно будет не брать вообще! Это заметно ускорят работу при большом количестве потоков реадеров и малом количестве потоков писателей. Очень хорошо эта тема рассказана на jpoin 2016, можете найти доклад на youtube на канале JUG.RU